# Operaciones con javaScript tiempo real

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando operaciones en tiempor real para unos tickets
por ahora tengo una problematica.

Tengo que multiplicar una cantidad fija, por una precio variable

Cantidad= este input es **tipo hidden**

```
input id="totalproducto"  class="" type="hidden"  name="totalProducto[]"
```

Precio =

```
input type="number" id="precio" name="precio[]" class="Can_Produc"
```

Total=

```
input class="form-control" disabled type="text" value="0" id="Inventario"
```

Necesito hacer la suma de la siguiente manera, multiplicando cantidad por precio.

```
Cantidad | Precio
1        | 1      = 1
2        | 1      = 2

      TotalPrecio = 3
```

Por ahora tengo este script

Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var cantidad = $('#totalproducto').val();
      var valor_inicial = $('#Inventario').val();

            $( document ).ready(function() {
                  $('.Can_Produc').keyup(function () {
                    var valor = parseInt(valor_inicial);
                    var valor_sumar = 0;
                       $('.Can_Produc').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() > 0) {
                           valor_sumar += parseInt($(this).val());
                         }
                        });
                               
                         $('#Inventario').val(valor + valor_sumar * parseInt(cantidad));
                   });
             });
    </script>
```

El problema es que  en la operación me da otro resultado, porque siempre multiplica por la cantidad de la primera posición

```
Cantidad | Precio
1        | 1      = 1
2        | 1      = 2

      TotalPrecio = 4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 @foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
  


    <form id="{{$ticket->id}}" action="{{ route('compradosData') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
       
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
                        

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @php
                        $ordenes = Orden::select(Orden::raw('count(sku) as total,sku'))
                        ->where('ticket', $ticket->id)
                        ->groupBy('sku')
                        ->get();
                    $datosOrden= Orden::distinct('sku')->where('ticket',$ticket->id)->get();
                 
                    $datosOrdenes = $datosOrden->unique('sku');
                    @endphp

                    @foreach ($ordenes as $key => $value)
                    @foreach ($datosOrdenes as $i => $j)
                    @if ($j['sku']== $value->sku && $j['ticket']==$ticket->id)

                   

                    @if ( $j['status'] == 'cancelado')


                    <tr class="bg-danger">
                        @else
                    <tr>
                        @endif

                        <th scope="row">{{$value->total}}
                            <input id="totalproducto{{$ticket->id}}" class="" type="hidden" name="totalProducto[]" value="{{$value->total}}">
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ticketid" value="{{$ticket->id}}">
                                <input type="number" id="precio" name="precio[]" class="form-control Can_Produc" step='0.01'
                                    placeholder="Ingrese precio unitario" value="{{$j['costo_unitario']}}"
                                  
                                    >
                            </div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    @endif
                    
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                   
                    <tr class="bg-warning">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="Inventario" class="form-control"  
    type="text" value="0" disabled>
                            <span id="aaa"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </form>
```

este es el codigo que utilizo actualmente

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Lo pondré en la descripcion

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código HTML con el que estás trabajando.

Comment: Donde tienes el `id="totalproducto"`?

Comment: en el primer input

Comment: No se muy bien como tienes los datos, si los tienes en una tabla, o si todos son ingresados por un input, pero estoy haciendo un ejemplo

Comment: Los datos de cantidad, viene de la base de datos, el input de precio se tiene que ingresar,

entonces si escribo 1 en precio, y tengo 2 en cantidad

necesito multiplicar 1 x2
 y lo mismo con la siguiente linea, porque es una tabla

Comment: Te siguieron que pongas el código html, en todo caso para hacerme una mejor idea una imagende tu web

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124076/discussion-between-christian-and-ivan).